# Python Tools for Visual Studio & virtualenv - can use packages only present in deactivated env

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, ptvs

I'm working on a Django project in VS 2015 Community with PTVS, which has been very useful for a free tool. I recently realized that I should be using virtual environments during development, and found out that Python 3 includes this feature by default, and PTVS 2.0+ supports it- cool!

I created a couple environments as an experiment, and in one I installed the celery[redis] bundle since I'm trying to figure out how to implement a background  task. I was having trouble getting the basic celery tutorial task to work, so I decided to remove the environment from my Django project, deactivate it, and start over.

However, once I removed it via PTVS and ran `deactivate` from the command line inside the environment directory, I could still run celery commands from my top-level project directory. I've never installed celery globally- only to my test environment via the Python Environments menu in PTVS.

Why is this? Am I thinking of virtual environments as too similar to truly discrete environments such as containers? My impression from reading PTVS venv documentation is that if a package is present in a virtual environment which is then deactivated, I shouldn't be able to use it in other environments (or globally). I thought it might be an issue with my Windows PATH, but I didn't see anything related to Python or celery.

Apologies if this is a duplicate- it's been difficult to find questions on the PTVS implementation of venv rather than Python + virtualenv in general.

Comment: Initial thoughts are its using its own copy version of the virtualenv and doesn't recognise your deactivate and therefore it hasn't had to update its cache. Reopening your program will probably confirm/deny this..

Comment: Thanks- I'll try reopening as soon as I'm back at my computer! What do you mean by 'its using its own copy of the virtualenv'? As in Visual Studio has an internal environment that reflects the chosen environment, but choosing to remove/deactivate doesn't take effect until close/reopen? This is my first time playing with virtualenv so I may have misunderstood.

Comment: PTVS just calls out to `venv` if it is there (Python 3.3 and later) or will install `virtualenv` and use that. There's no special implementation. It's not clear from the question whether you are running a script that imports and uses the environment or whether you just want to use the command line. Probably best to do the latter without using VS at all.